# Arrow => in Perl

Tags: data-structures, perl

What does the `=>` mean in Perl?

```
my $CreateArray = [
objectClass => [ "top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "inetOrgPerson" ],
cn => "Jane User",
uid => "0000001",
sn => "User",
mail => "JaneUser@mycompany.com"
];
```

produces

```
CreateArray:
0  'objectClass'
1  ARRAY(0x104ef40)
  0  'top'
  1  'person'
  2  'organizationalPerson'
  3  'inetOrgPerson'
2  'cn'
3  'Jane User'
4  'uid'
5  0000001
6  'sn'
7  'User'
8  'mail'
9  'JaneUser@mycompany.com'
```

It seems that even numbers are keys and odd numbers are values. Why don't they use hashes? Because they aren't ordered? Is there a name for this strange structure?

Thank you.

Comment: A name for the structure in the top code box or the bottom? Please clarify a bit so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I meant both boxes and especially the "comma operator". I didn't know this term and thought it's a hash. I didn't know that flat structures are used for pairs of keys and values.

Comment: There's also a [winking fat comma](http://search.cpan.org/~book/perlsecret-1.001/lib/perlsecret.pod#Winking_fat_comma_,=>).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, the "big arrow" (`=>`) in Perl is basically a comma, with one difference: everything on its left is treated as if it is quoted. So this:

```
Foo => Bar
```

Is the same as:

```
'Foo', Bar
```

For more info, see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator).

Comment: The left hand side is only quoted if it's strictly composed of Perl identifier characters.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, see perlop (perldoc perlop) for details.

For more discussion, here's a decent thread.  Don't confuse the key=>value notation as being significant to a hash...

For example:

```
# no =>
my %hash = (
  mykey, 'blah',
  yourkey, 'blah2',
  seehere, 'blah3',
  90, 'see further -- try putting a 0 in front of my key');

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash) {
  print qq#$key: $hash{$key}\n#;
}

exit(0);
```

But arrows will do just as well, without quotes, avoid unquoted octals.

Reference: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=381320